# Is it ok to save complex object with activity reference in Android ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I'm using a lib that uses an interface I pass by to communicate with the calling activity, the problem is once I rotate the device the new instance of the activity wouldn't receive the callback anymore. I was thinking in saving an instance of this lib in a AndroidViewModel, would I get a memory issue doing so because the instance of the lib references my activity?

Causes problem when rotating:

```
public class MainActivity implements Lib.Callback
    {
        private Lib mLib;

        @Override
        public void onCreate ( final Bundle savedInstanceState){
            mLib = new Lib(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void callback() {
          ...
        }
    }
```

Makes it better if I put "mLib" in an AndroidViewModel? Or is there a better alternative for such a case?

Comment: Yes, lib will leak if it lives beyond the Activity lifecycle. You could use an event bus to dispatch the event from the callback if it's in a ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do so you will leak the Activity. 
And you still will have only the old instance. Not the new one. 
Implement the callback for example in the ViewModel and then expose some LiveData from the ViewModel which the Activity can observe. It will work on device rotation.

Answer (score 0):

> Would I get a memory issue doing so because the instance of the lib references my activity?

Saving lib reference in `ViewModel` will cause memory leak for your 
scenario.As your lib has reference of `Activity`,  when you rotate your phone that lib will hold a reference of your old activity.